# Callback and curly braces in C?

Tags: c, callback, curly-braces

I’m trying to port a script written in C (in which I have zero knowledge) into JavaScript or PHP. So far, I’ve been OK figuring out most of it, but there’s a function here that eludes me.

In the file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Stellarium/stellarium/master/src/core/planetsephems/calc_interpolated_elements.c, the “main” function is `CalcInterpolatedElements`, but then in its parameters we find `void (*calc_func)(const double t,double elem[],void *user)`.

What is this (*calc_func) and what does it do? It seems like, at first, the function `CalcInterpolatedElements` is called with empty arrays, which are… somewhat (?) populated (?) by `(*calc_func)` from… I don’t know… Ugh!

Can someone please help?

Comment: You should have a look at the code that calls this function, and analyse what is the function provided as a parameter.

Comment: @Damien: That’s what I tried doing, but not knowing/understanding C, it’s something I can’t figure out. That’s why I asked here…

Answer (score 1):

```
void (*calc_func)(const double t,double elem[],void *user)
```

`calc_func` is a pointer to a function that takes three parameters with no return value (`void`).

I suggest viewing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) on SO.

Comment: I get that, but I can’t see what the function is… What happens to t, elem[], and *user? In other words, what function does it point to?

Comment: That depends on the implementation of the function you pass a pointer to. `calc_func` can point to **_any_** function that takes those parameters and returns `void`.

Comment: Ouch! I have no clue what that is… That’s why I was asking here…

Comment: Did you review the article I linked to in my answer?

Comment: Yes, but a) it’s almost Chinese to me, and b) I understand that `calc_func` is a pointer, but it doesn’t tell me—and I can’t figure out—where to…

Comment: It points to a function. Which function it points to is decided when the function is called. Consider a very simple `add` function `int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }`  Normally we call this like: `add(2, 3)` and get `5`. What if I define a function `apply` that takes two ints and a function pointer as parameters and calls the function being pointed to with those two integers.  `int apply(int a, int b, int (*f)(int, int)) { return (*f)(a, b); }`  Now I can call: `apply(2, 7, add)` and I get `9`.